# How to delay hide event with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a show/hide function on a hover triggered dropdown that I'm trying to tweak right now. What I would like is for the dropdown to appear on hover, but when the mouse leaves wait about 500 ms before it drops back up, *unless* the mouse has left and hovered on another li item (I haven't even addressed this second condition yet, since I've been unsuccessful in meeting the first).

Here is a jsfiddle of what I have so far...
http://jsfiddle.net/u4e1tv21/12/

I've done some digging and I tried changing this bit of js

```
$('[data-toggle="menu"]').on('mouseleave', function (ev) {
    var id = $(this).data('target');
    $('.sub-menu').hide();
    $(id).hide();
});
```

to this

```
$('[data-toggle="menu"]').on('mouseleave', function (ev) {
    var id = $(this).data('target');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.sub-menu').hide();
        $(id).hide();
    }; 2000);
});
```

Judging by the fact that the change just broke the event entirely, I know I haven't got it quite right. However I can't seem to figure out what is the right way of doing it. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use `delay(2000)`?

Comment: You have a syntax error. The `;` before `2000` should be `,`. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/u4e1tv21/16/

Comment: Didn't you get an error in the Javascript console from that?

Comment: @Remy I'm going to sound a little stupid here, but I'm just learning jQuery as of this week and I don't know where I would add that on. (:

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! That was incredibly helpful.

Comment: @SSA I'm just going to vote to close the question because it's just a typo. P.S. Please use name auto-completion so you spell names correctly after @.

Comment: @SSA Barmar, not Barmer :)

Comment: @Barmar I decided not to delete my answer since the OP wants to know how to delay with jQuery as opposed to his trial of vanilla js for delaying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `delay(duration)`

```
$('.sub-menu').delay(500).hide(0);
$(id).delay(500).hide(0);
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: I tried this out but it didn't seem to affect anything...
http://jsfiddle.net/u4e1tv21/14/
Did I add it wrong?

Comment: @Maddi `delay()` works on jQuery animations, to get this to work, you need to give `hide()` a duration => http://jsfiddle.net/u4e1tv21/17/

Comment: @AminJafari 0 works as well and makes it instantaneous.

Comment: @Arbel the problem was that without any number (just `.hide()`) delay didn't work at all.

Comment: Thanks guys! All these methods were appreciated, I feel like I understand jQuery much better after reading through this. Arbel's answer is what I was originally trying to do.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad to be of help to you. Also thanks to @AminJafari for his input.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you might need is to use here is the `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` effects

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sub-menu').hide();

    $('[data-toggle="menu"]').on('mouseenter', function (ev) {
        var id = $(this).data('target');
        $('.sub-menu').slideUp();
        $(id).slideDown();
    });
    $('[data-toggle="menu"]').on('mouseleave', function (ev) {
        var id = $(this).data('target');
        $('.sub-menu').slideUp();
        $(id).slideUp();
    });
});
```

with this effect you will have a nice and neat in and out animation of the sub-menu with no need to use two effect functions like `delay().hide()` *which will work also* but slideUp and slideDown() will make it shorter in my opinion.

an updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/u4e1tv21/20/

Comment: With fast switching between elements it won't look nice. Moreover, if you trigger `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events faster than animation works, it ends up in several slidings after you've stopped hovering element. I suggest to add `.stop()` before each slide animation to fix these problems.